# Is there a way while using tail to get it to tell number of lines without using cat?

Tags: debian, cat, tail

I'll share an example so it makes sense -

```
[$] cat /boot/config-4.9.0-1-amd64 | tail

  7856  CONFIG_FONT_SUPPORT=y
  7857  # CONFIG_FONTS is not set
  7858  CONFIG_FONT_8x8=y
  7859  CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
  7860  # CONFIG_SG_SPLIT is not set
  7861  CONFIG_SG_POOL=y
  7862  CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SG_CHAIN=y
  7863  CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_PMEM_API=y
  7864  CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_MMIO_FLUSH=y
  7865  CONFIG_SBITMAP=y
```

The output is what I want without using cat , cat here is aliased to -

```
[$] alias cat

cat='cat -n'
```

Using `tail -n` is good only if I want to have more number of lines included in tail.

How do I do a tail listing which shows real-line numbers without resorting to cat , is there a way ?

Comment: `tail` or even `multitail` don't have the inbuilt ability to show line numbers.

Comment: @shirish I suppose answers bellow do not cover your question.... Do you had something different in mind?

Comment: not really, the thing is it comes down to the same, the character count remains the same or even more , whether I use nl or sed or awk or whatever. I was looking to make the count lower.

Answer (score 6):

`cat -n` for cat haters:

- With GNU `sed`:

  ```
  sed = file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/' | tail
  ```
- With `awk`:

  ```
   awk '{ $0 = NR "\t" $0 } 1' file.txt | tail
  ```
- With `grep` and GNU `sed`:

  ```
  grep -n ^ file.txt | sed 's/:/\t/' | tail
  ```
- With `perl`:

  ```
  perl -lpe '$_ = qq($.\t$_)' | tail
  ```

  or

  ```
  perl -pe 'print "$.\t"' file.txt | tail
  ```
- With `bash`, `paste` and `seq`:

  ```
  paste <(seq 1 $(wc -l <file.txt)) file.txt | tail
  ```
- With `pr`:

  ```
  pr -n -t -l 1 file.txt | tail
  ```
- With plain `sh`:

  ```
  let cnt=0
  while read -r line; do
      let cnt\+\+
      printf '%d\t%s\n' $cnt "$line"
  done <file.txt | tail
  ```
- With `vim`:

  ```
  :%s/^/\=line('.')."\t"/ | $-10,$y | new | P
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [nl utility](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/coreutils/nl.1.en.html) (part of coreutils present by default in most distros)? 
Is this what you are looking for?

```
$ tail /boot/config-4.9.0-1-amd64 |nl 
# Or even nl <(tail /boot/config-4.9.0-1-amd64)

     1  CONFIG_FONT_SUPPORT=y
     2  # CONFIG_FONTS is not set
     3  CONFIG_FONT_8x8=y
     4  CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
     5  # CONFIG_SG_SPLIT is not set
     6  CONFIG_SG_POOL=y
     7  CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SG_CHAIN=y
     8  CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_PMEM_API=y
     9  CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_MMIO_FLUSH=y
    10  CONFIG_SBITMAP=y
```

nl can provide a lot of interesting numbering options, like starting number, number increase step,etc

To simulate the cat numbering, just use `nl /boot/config-4.9.0-1-amd64 |tail`

Comment: @Sato Katsura Do you think that  is it a bit unfair for me to add nl solution to your combo post 5 minutes after my answer?

Comment: Actually I added it as I thought of it, without reading your answer.  But sure, I'll remove it if you prefer your answer to be the the unique repository of that piece of knowledge.  Feel free to downvote my answer for that (unintentional) plagiarism.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thank you for answering. No reason to downvote. I will upvote your combo answer and your responsible attitude in this issue.